# Visual Basic Search Script

Tags: search, vbscript, wmi

I obtained this script from another site, and attempted to modify it to search more than two drives, specifically I wanted it to search almost every drive possible, but as soon as i add a third drive letter the script does not work.

```
 strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from CIM_DataFile Where Extension = 'mdb' AND (Drive = 'B:' OR Drive = 'C:' OR Drive = 'D:')")

' If colFiles.Count = 0 Then
'     Wscript.Quit
' End If

Set objTextFile = wshfso.CreateTextFile("c:\temp\" & vComputer & ".txt " , True)

For Each objFile in colFiles
    objTextFile.Write(objFile.Drive & objFile.Path & "")
    objTextFile.Write(objFile.FileName & "." & objFile.Extension & ", Size ")
    objTextFile.Write(objFile.FileSize /1024 & "kb" & vbCrLf)
Next
```

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work"? Please describe.

Comment: Should have been more specific, nothing is written to the text file, additionally if i uncomment the If colFiles line the count returns 0 and quits.

Comment: However, if i only have drives b: and c: in the query, the script dumps to the text file and there is data.

Comment: You make sure to browse for each drive finding it by its own kind of drive. I mean: browse physical drives, logical drives, and so on. Then, merge results. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394592(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You've got 2 variables, "vComputer" and "strComputer".